# Viewcontroller comes beneath tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm having a `tabBarController` with a `tableView` in each tab. The `tableView` displays fine even the last cell is completely visible.

When you click on a cell then you go to a pageViewController. The pageViewController goes under the tabBar for some reason. So the dots ( the pageView indicator ) isn't visible.

I've tried to set this on my tabBarController:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:) withObject:@(UIRectEdgeNone)];
}

self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

but still the view comes under the tabBar.

Someone who could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when you set the translucent property only in the tabbarcontroller it gets overwritten or something.

So I just added this line to set it for my whole app:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

This fixed the problem. Only add this line, the ones in my post are redundant.